# Resampling multiple data columns from minutes to hours in matlab

Tags: matlab

I got a big data set of minutly data with multiple columns that needs to be converted from minutes to hours.

I am new to matlab and tried

```
data_minute = rand(data);  % synthetic data
data_hour = mean(reshape(data_minute, 60, []))
```

which only gives me the hourly data from one row.

I wasnt able to work through every column with something like:

```
for i = 1:n_columns
data_hour(:,i) = mean(reshape(data_minute(:,i),60, []));
end
```

Trying a For-Loop to sample every 60 data plots also didn't work out.

Looking at a solution in google didn't give me a result i understood.

**Update:**

For clarification the data looks something like this:

```
minute   value
1   501
2   479
3   449
4   463
5   404
6   173
7   141
8   141
9   141
10  140
11  140
12  140
13  140
14  202
15  206
16  206
..  ...
525604 120
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Seconds in the first column and the measured value in every column afterwards. Each column needs to be resampled alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`timetable`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/timetables.html) and [`retime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/retime.html). First make a `timetable`, using a [`duration`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html) for the "time" variable - it's easy to create a `duration` array using the [`minutes`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/minutes.html) function. For example:

```
>> tt = timetable(minutes(0:1000)', rand(1001, 1));
>> % Just look at the first few rows of 'tt':
>> head(tt)
ans =
  8×1 timetable
    Time       Var1  
    _____    ________
    0 min     0.31907
    1 min     0.98605
    2 min     0.71818
    3 min     0.41318
    4 min     0.09863
    5 min     0.73456
    6 min     0.63731
    7 min    0.073842
>> % use 'retime' to get the hourly means:
>> rt = retime(tt, 'hourly', 'mean')
rt =
  17×1 timetable
     Time       Var1  
    _______    _______
    0 min      0.47755
    60 min     0.47877
    120 min    0.48007
    180 min    0.55399
    240 min     0.5142
    300 min     0.5656
    360 min    0.50957
    420 min    0.48986
    480 min    0.49568
    540 min    0.55133
    600 min    0.49981
    660 min    0.53677
    720 min    0.49343
    780 min    0.53409
    840 min    0.47901
    900 min    0.55287
    960 min    0.48173
```

Answer (score 1):

**We want to: Downsample the data with an aggregation or an interpolation of all the measurements grouped by hour.**

If we take this example data matrice:

```
M = [10,   3,4,5,6;
     2000, 3,4,3,5;
     5000, 4,4,4,4]
```

And we say that the first column correspond to the time in second, and the other columns correspond to your measurements.

**Solution 1:** **Aggregation with accumarray**

```
% we start by calculating the time in hour (3600 seconds in one hour).
hour = ceil(M(:,1)/3600)

% We extract the measurements
val = M(:,2:end)

% nrow = How many different measurements ?
nrow = size(val,2);

% How many unique hour ?
[uid,~,id] = unique(hour);

% creation of a sub index grouping the measurements by hour and by column
sub = [repmat(id,nrow,1),kron(1:nrow,ones(1,length(id))).']
```

> ```
> sub = 
>    1   1
>    1   1
>    2   1
>    1   2
>    1   2
>    2   2
>    1   3
>    1   3
>    2   3
>    1   4
>    1   4
>    2   4
> ```

```
%We calculate the result using accumarray (first column = hour):
RES = [uid,accumarray(sub,val(:),[],@median)] %if you want the mean choose @mean
```

> ```
> RES =
>
> 1.0000   3.0000   4.0000   4.0000   5.5000
> 2.0000   4.0000   4.0000   4.0000   4.0000
> ```

**Solution 2:** **Interpolation with interp1**

You can interpolate your data with `interp1`

```
interp_second = unique(floor(M(:,1)/3600))*3600

%création of an unique index
uid = unique(ceil(M(:,1)/3600))

% We extract the measurements
val = M(:,2:end)

% Result (first column = hour)
RES = [uid,interp1(M(:,1),val,interp_second)]
```

**Conclusion**

I would recommand the **solution 1**, because the method is more robust.

Comment: Trying out the first solution i get a matrix with 146 rows. The result should have 8760 rows. This is how the first 15 data points of the original are organized (min;value).

1; 95
2; 95
3; 95
4; 95
5; 99
6; 115
7; 113
8; 212
9; 235
10; 198
11; 131
12; 131
13; 131
14; 131
15; 131

Comment: If you want to add more information please edit your question don't add a comment. The answer show you the way to go, of course you have to adapt the code for your specific case...

Comment: By the way multiply 146 by 60 you will obtain 8760, and there is 60second in a minute... Mhhhh interesting :P

Comment: ...just realized my mistake. I have minutes not seconds in my first row.. well it was a long day.

Comment: Tried the code now and did not find the solution. Check out the update. Changing hour = ceil(M(:,1)/3600) to hour = ceil(M(:,1)/60) did not work. As the result i get a  2x2 matrix